# Can I do "Collection group queries" to Firestore from Cloud Function using firebase_functions_interop?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Please I need some help:

Can I do "Collection group queries" to Firestore from Cloud Function using firebase_functions_interop?

firebase_functions_interop: https://github.com/pulyaevskiy/firebase-functions-interop

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a quick glance the `firebase_functions_interop` library does't seem to yet implement Collection Group Queries. I noticed that you also filed an [issue on the repo](https://github.com/pulyaevskiy/firebase-functions-interop/issues/60), which should probably be turned into a feature request.